# Restrict users access using shiro ZeppelinHub Realm

Tags: shiro, apache-zeppelin

**Goal**

I'd want a group of people to have access to our spark/zeppelin cluster. For that I use the shiro authentication configuration as explained on the [zeppelin website](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/security/shiroauthentication.html#zeppelinhub) which basically comes down to adding the following to your shiro.ini

```
### A sample for configuring ZeppelinHub Realm
zeppelinHubRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.ZeppelinHubRealm
## Url of ZeppelinHub
zeppelinHubRealm.zeppelinhubUrl = https://www.zeppelinhub.com
securityManager.realms = $zeppelinHubRealm
```

**Problem**

The problem is that it seems that everyone with a zeppelinhub account can access this server.

**Question**

How can I restrict access to only those users with a zeppelinhub account that I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there are no way to do that, but i heard that zeppelinhub will have organization concept so my guess is that they will provide a way to login user to a zeppelin with a specific organization.